# Time zone updates are only semi-automatic

Tags: calendar, system-settings, timezone

In my Mac's date and time prefs I have "Set time zone automatically using current location" checked. But when I travel to a different time zone, the zone doesn't automatically change-- unless I open Date & Time preferences. I don't have to **do** anything once I open it, just opening it is enough to make the time zone update. It automatically finds the correct time zone but only once I open the prefs.

The Mac can determine the correct time zone, so that's fine, but isn't it supposed to actually change it automatically if I have that setting turned on?

OS X 10.11.1, MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)